# Python regex get all matches all with findall

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have this string:

```
string = 'start asf[2]+asdfsa[0]+fsad[1]'
```

I would like to extract the integers above into an array in the order in which they appear in the string:

```
[2, 0, 1]
```

I've tried findall but it doesn't work:

```
print re.findall(r'start .*\[(.)\]', string)
```

It outputs:

```
['1']
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: You should probably separate the "does the line starts with `start`" filter from the extraction of the numbers. If you really want to do both these actions in a single regex, use the third-party `regex` module which supports variable-width lookbehinds and match `(?<=start .*)\[(.)\]`

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, what is the most elegant way to do this without any third-party library?

Comment: My python is rusty, but `if string.startswith("start"): print(re.findall(r'\[(.)\]', string))` looks good to me for 1-line strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach

```
>>> regex = re.compile("(?<=\[)([0-9]){1}?(?=\])")
>>> string = 'start asf[2]+asdfsa[0]+fsad[1]'
>>> re.findall(regex, string)
['2', '0', '1']
```

**DEMO**

```
>>> import re
>>> def get_all_integers_between_square_brackets(*, regex, string):
...     return map(int, re.findall(regex, string))
...
>>> regex = re.compile("(?<=\[)([0-9]){1}?(?=\])")
>>> integers = get_all_integers_between_square_brackets(
                               regex=regex , 
                               string='start asf[2]+asdfsa[0]+fsad[1]'
                               )
>>> list(integers)
[2, 0, 1]

>>> integers = get_all_integers_between_square_brackets(
                          regex=regex, 
                          string='start asf[hello]+asdfsa[world]+fsad[1][2][]')
>>> list(integers)
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a small change to the above answer. 
The above answer fetch only if it is a single digit number.

```
expression = re.compile("(?<=\[)([0-9]+)(?=\])")
```

This will return all the digits inside the [ ]

**Example**

```
string='start asf[123]+asdfsa[0]+fsad[1]
output = [123, 0, 1]
```

**Code**

```
>>>import re
>>>def fetch_digits(expression, string):
     ...return map(int, re.findall(expression, string))

>>>expression = re.compile("(?<=\[)([0-9]+)(?=\])")
>>>int_map = fetch_digits(expression,'start asf[123]+asdfsa[0]+fsad[1]')
>>>list(int_map)
```